# ошибка No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java

Создал приложение на java swing в windows, и сохранил проект на гитлабе. Хотел проверить в ubunutu как оно работает, но столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it

В этом же проекте создал тестовый класс с JFrame и он тоже выдал такую ошибку. Когда создал другой workspace и сделал тестовый фрейм, он заработал.

Простые классы из первого проекта (без фреймов) запускаются.

Можете пожалуйста подсказать с чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. ссылку Baeldung [Meaning and Resolving “No X11 DISPLAY” and Related Errors](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/no-x11-display-error) или на основной сайт SO: [Getting a HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/) или [Unable to run Java GUI programs with Ubuntu (JDK 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/)

Comment: Спасибо! Я немного разобрался. Оказалось, что на той версии java, вылетала такая ошибка, я запустил на другой версии и всё заработало.